# как умножить две двухмерные матрицы и занести этот результат в динамический массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Не понимаю, как их между собой умножить и занести результат в новый динамический массив.
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int rows = 4;                    // через константу задаём количество рядов, а ниже столбцов
    const int cols = 5;

    int A[rows][cols];
    
    cout << "Matrix A : \n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)         // с помощью данного цикла for сначала наполняем матрицу А, а после её выводим
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 10; 
            cout << A[i][j] << "\t"; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    int B[rows][cols];                    
    
    cout << "\n\nMatrix B : \n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)         // с помощью данного цикла for сначала наполняем матрицу B, а после её выводим
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            B[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << B[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
                                                   

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В данном случае — никак. Для того, чтобы матрицы можно было множить, число столбцов в первой должно быть равно числу строк во второй...

Comment: ну может мы не знаем, что именно имеет автор ввиду под словом "умножить". может поэлементно.

Comment: @Harry, то есть проще ее сделать 4х4 к примеру?

Comment: Т.е. множить надо матрицу NxM на матрицу MxK...